# How can I access IEnumerable<T> extension methods on my custom subclass of BindingList<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I have a custom subclass of BindingList<T> that I want to execute a LINQ query over using the handy extension methods.  For example:

```
public int GetSum(MyList<T> list)
{
   return list.Sum(x => x.Value);
}
```

But the compiler complains that it can't resolve `Sum` because it doesn't recognize `list` as an `IEnumerable<T>`, which it obviously is, because this works:

```
public int GetSum(MyList<T> list)
{
   return ((IEnumerable<T>)list).Sum(x => x.Value);
}
```

Anyone have a clever way I can avoid the ugly and unecessary cast?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear the compiler might be complaining about the type argument which the `Sum` is attempting to be performed on since it can not be inferred. You can specify the type argument like this; where T is the type you want to perform the `Sum` on.

```
return list.Sum<T>(x => x.Value);
```

It should be noted however that neither of your samples compiles for me even when reverting to the base `BindingList<T>` without setting the type argument.

Comment: That must be it.... do you think that's because there are multiple IEnumerable<T> implementations on the type?

Comment: @Dan Within your Sum(x => x.Value) x.Value removes the ability that this expression can evaluate in to something across all objects; you are now specifying a type which must have a property of Value to evaluate properly. Unless you specify the type within the type argument of the Sum extension method it has no idea how to evaluate the expression.